# Stuck creating new Ember project in WebStorm with Ember.js plugin

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, ember.js, webstorm

I'm getting stuck creating a new project using the Ember plugin with WebStorm. At the bottom it says `/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0/bin/node "" init --name=untitled` and there's a line that just keeps spinning under it.

Is it missing the script for node to run and what should I look at to fix this? I tried specifying some different path for node and ember but it didn't help.

[image]

Comment: from the screenshot it seems that path to ember-cli package is empty. Did you specify it in *New | Project | Ember CLI app*, *Ember CLI:*?

Comment: I'd suggest reporting this issue to https://github.com/Turbo87/intellij-emberjs/issues; meanwhile, please try creating the project in terminal, by running `ember new my-new-app` and then opening `my-new-app` folder in webstorn via **File | Open**

Comment: @lena I tried creating it in terminal but I'm not sure if it's working. The Ember module imports show up in editor with wavy underline ("Module is not installed") and if I try to debug I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import". (What project file should I use to start debugging?)

Comment: I believe that you need starting Ember server and then use *javascript debug* run configuration with `http://localhost:4200` URL to debug your app.

Comment: Thanks @lena. I'm started with javascript debug now and it looked like it worked but my breakpoints aren't working right. It hit only one of my breakpoints and then I still wasn't able to step through the code. It jumps into some library code when I step forward and then never returns.